# How to handle dual java .jars for Xpages on domino server?

Tags: java, jar, xpages, lotus-domino

I could need some help.

I want to use Xpages that communicates with java source. Actually I get a problem by  importing the ReferencedLibraries of the Java project. 
This standalone project has many java packages in use, so I think domino gets trouble by using them.

I'm not sure, but I think it's because there are some libraries/packages twice now.
Once on domino and once in the imported library of the java project.

Has anybody an idea or experience how I could get it work?
Is there a way to find double packages?
Or is domino able to use one of them?

I don't want to proof and deselect every library by hand. That would be a big effort and would not make sense because I have to to it again if the new release of the java project is comming.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Importing Java packages is certainly possible. You'd have to provide more details what issues you're seeing.

Domino uses OSGi. So you can use OSGi capabilities, e.g. "exact match" in your dependency definition.

Are you trying to import the libraries into an NSF or as OSGi bundle?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.                                         I'm testing it local and I got it work by pasting the jars into the _Lotus\Notes\jvm\lib\ext_ folder. But I didn't get it done by importing the libraries into an nsf. Do you know a way how I can do this? It would be great to have the needed jars in the .nsf